# BASH Linux- How to pass the result of find into a for loop

Tags: bash, sh

I get a local directory that contains different Git repos in it. The directory tree is something like this:

```
Dir
- dir1  --- repo1
- dir2  --- repo2
- dir3  --- repo3
```

I want to create a Bash script that use the `find` command to get all the `.git` directory names, and then pass all the paths in a `for` loop to `git pull` all the updates from the remote repo. 
Therefore, I can update all the repos by running this bash script.

Can anyone give a hint on how to do this? Relevant documentation is also helpful.

Comment: Don't use `for`; use `while read` and use `-print0` so that you can handle names with blanks etc — or not if your sure you don't have odd-ball characters in your repo directory names.  You'll need to make an informed decision about whether any of the paths will ever contain spaces (or tabs, or newlines).  Even without space, using `read` is still good, though `for` can also be used.  Look up [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) and [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, this feels like the start of a decent Answer...

Comment: @jdv: yeah, but only the start, and there are only a myriad duplicates that could be identified if it were easier to identify duplicates.  I'm too lazy to complete the job.

Comment: I'll agree that there probably are a fair number of near-dups for this one, and shell scripting is, at best, an exercise in there's more than one way to do it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your advice and the references. They are really helpful! I just started learning bash script a few weeks ago and I need to learn more about it.

Comment: Don't use `for` to iterate over the output of a command, but *do* use `for` if you can iterate over a simply pattern, like `for f in **/*.git/; do ... ; done`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a rather different approach, one which exploits `find`'s capability to run commands.

```
cd Dir             # Change to the top-level directory
find . -type d -name .git -exec \
     sh -c 'for d in "$@"; do (cd "$d/.."; git pull) done' argv0 {} +
```

This changes directory to the top level directory, and then runs `find` to locate the `.git` directories.  The command after the `-exec` is executed, with each Git directory name taking the place of `{}` in the script, and the `+` means as many such names as are convenient will be used in a single command execution.  The command executed is:

```
sh -c 'for d in "$@"; do (cd "$d/.." && git pull) done' argv0 dir1/.git dir2/.git …
```

The `argv0` argument is the `$0` of the shell script run via `-c '…'` — you could use a name such as `git-multi-pull` if you preferred.  That script processes each argument in turn, carefully preserving spaces, through `(cd "$d/.." && git pull)` which changes directory to the top-level directory of the repository and runs `git pull`.  The `(…)` runs the operations in a sub-shell, which means that if there is a problem (hard to see what it would be, but just in case), only the one child sub-shell is affected.  There's no need to try to get back to the correct location for the next `cd` — the previous sub-shell exited without affecting the `sh -c '…'` shell. The advantage of this is that all the eccentric characters in file names are handled automatically and completely.

This is the 'type it at the command line' version.  You could make it into a script by removing the `cd Dir` and replacing `.` with `"${@:-.}"` in the `find` command.  You then specify the directory or directories to be searched for Git repos as command line arguments, or use the current directory if there are no command line arguments.

You can add a `pwd` or `echo "$d"` to the shell script to echo directory names as you go, which gives you progress tracking.  If you wanted, you could demonstrate that the `argv0` is the `$0` with:

```
sh -c 'for d in "$@"; do (cd "$d/.." && echo "$0: $PWD" && git pull) done' git-multi-pull {} +
```

If you're into cryptic shell scripting, you can omit the `in "$@"`; it is implied when you write `for d; do (…) done`.  Also note that when the whole body of the loop is a sub-shell, you don't need a semicolon before the `done`; the `)` suffices.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear if all your repositories are on the same directory level, but it appears they are from your question. From that standpoint, there is no need to call `find`, simply use globbing, e.g.

```
for dir in */; do                     ## for each dir under present
    if [ -d "$dir/.git" ]; then       ## does it have a .git dir?
        pushd "$dir" >/dev/null 2>&1  ## if so, change to it
        git pull                      ## update repo
        popd >/dev/null 2>&1          ## change back to original dir
    fi
done
```

There are many variations. I use `pushd` and `popd` to avoid having to parse the path or use `..`. You can `cd "$dir"` and then `cd ..` if you like.

---

With directories not all on the same level, you can use `find`, and if you are looking for the shortest implementation, it would probably go something like:

```
cwd="$PWD"                                        ## save current path
for dir in $(find . -type d -name "*\.git"); do   ## loop over all with .git
    dname="${dir#./}"                             ## trim leading './'
    cd "$cwd/${dname%/.git}" && git pull          ## change to and git pull
done
```

Let me know if that is better for you.

Comment: Another way is to use a sub-shell: `(cd "$i" && git pull)`.  One advantage is that you don't lose error messages, or reprocess the current directory if you fail to change directory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed, but `for dir in */` will only provide relative paths, so I would have to save `$PWD` first as `topdir="$PWD"` and then we could do `cd "$topdir/$dir" && git pull`"  `ch` ... **yep**

Comment: I know it wasn't mentioned in the OP but what if you had a directory hierarchy that wasn't so flat? Say `dir1/.git` and `dir2/dirA/.git` etc ...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Really appreciate for the two versions of command. The commands work for me though I don't fully understand what's going on here (I am a beginner of bash script). Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad it helped. If my answer was useful to you, you can select it as answering your question at the top left.

Answer (score 0):

EXEC function

```
find / "*.git" -type d -exec git pull {} \;
```

you may use the exec function of find command. it acts on the results fetched from find. In the above, it will search from / directory for all the git directories/repos in your system , and  once the directories are found, it will do a git pull on them.

Hope this resolves your issue

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
for i in `find . -type d -name .git`
do
 dir=`dirname $i`
 pushd .
 cd $dir
 git pull
 popd
done
```

Comment: Much better to use `$(…)` in place of back-ticks (which are hell to expose in comments).

Comment: Yes. I still do work on very old systems that just have plain old borne shell.

Comment: Old versions of Solaris?  The question is for Bash on Linux, but using backticks is sometimes necessary if you have to work on old systems.

Answer (score -1):

You can force `IFS` to only include `\n` as word delimiter, so you can do something like

```
IFS='
'               #only a new line.
for i in `find . -type d`
do
    if [ -d "$i/.git" ]
    then
        foo_bar "$i"
    fi
done
```

and this will not only work on bash, but in standard bourne shell (including upto UNIX(tm) V7!!!)

## EDIT 1

Better is to do

```
find . -type d ... |\
while read dir
do
    if [ -d "$i/.git" ]
    then
        foo_bar "$i"  # or `basename "$i"` or whatever you like.
    fi
done
```

of course, you can go directly to the `.git` repositories with

```
find . -type d -name .git |\
while read git_repo
do
    foo_bar `dirname "$i"`
done
```

if you know that all repos are under this level, just do

```
for repo in */.git
do
    repo_name=`dirname "$repo"`
    foo_bar "$repo_name"
done
```

for example, as you notice in your question

```
for repo in */.git
do
    (   cd `dirname "$repo"`
        git pull
    )   # subshell it to conserve current dir in parent shell.
done
```

(syntax is compatible with all Bourne Shells, not bash(1) specific)